# How to wrap custom C++ types for use with pybind11 if they can be initialized with literals?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm embedding a Python interpreter into my C++ code with pybind11.

I want to call C++ functions from Python code, so I have to wrap them first. Unfortunately, they take all kinds of custom types as parameters.

`void func_i_like_to_use(CustomeType a, AnotherCustomeType b);`

Typically, I would now start to wrap those too, but they are a deep hierarchy of inheritance mixed with a lot of template classes and typedef'ed names in between. In other words: it would be a real pain to replicate the whole tree.

```
//... more BaseTemplate hierarchy

template <T>
class CustomTemplate<T>: public BaseTemplate<T>;

typedef CustomTemplate<float> CustomType;
```

Thankfully, almost all parameters can be initialized with plain literals or enum-values. Mostly because they have constructors that relay those POD types deeper into the class tree or because they have type conversion features.

`function_i_like_to_use(5.7, "My string literal");`

Now from Python, it would totally suffice to use those literal forms. Is there a way to wrap these functions with alternative types that would work when calling the function with, but which do not match the actual function parameter types as declared?

```
PYBIND_EMBEDDED_MODULE(example, m)
{

// this compiles, but can't be called with literals
m.def("func_i_like_to_use", &func_i_like_to_use, "Want to call from Python",
      pybind11::arg("a"), pybind11::arg("b"))
}

// this doesn't compile, as it doesn't match the function declaration
m.def("func_i_like_to_use", static_cast<void (*)(float, std::string)>(&func_i_like_to_use), "Want to call from Python",
      pybind11::arg("a"), pybind11::arg("b"))
}

pybind11::exec("import example"
        "example.func_i_like_to_use(5.8, 'hello world')");
```

How could I get this to work? I could wrap the function again in C++ with POD parameters, but sometimes, even if calling a function with literals works, calling them with POD types doesn't, so I can't relay the wrapped parameters to the original function.

I could wrap the first order of CustomType with pybind11, but wrapping the actual constructors isn't sufficient to allow calling with literals. Maybe I could insert 'virtual' constructors here for use just by Python? How would this work with pybind11?

(**Update**: fixed usage of pybind11::arg(); modified experimental function bind with static_cast)

Comment: Nothing in your code compiles... `pybind11::arg` cannot be called like this, that's not even valid C++, do you mean `pybind11::arg(CustomType{})`? The `pybind11::arg` are simply the default value for your python function, nothing to do with the actual types.

Comment: What do you mean calling a function sometimes doesn't work with POD types? If you want to avoid needing to wrap your custom types, you'll need to wrap it yourself or use lambdas in your pybind11 code

Comment: @Holt: I fixed the usage of pybind11::arg in the examples. It's indeed not menat for type information, but name only. It's optional within the .def() call anyway. Parameter types are either deduced automatically (specified with static_cast in case of overloaded functions) (I can't use the C++14 notation here)

Comment: @vitalstatistix Could you maybe give me an example with lambdas? I tried a version with static casts that I also used for overloaded functions, but it still relies on an existing C++ declaration with these types. Translating a literal to a POD type in a wrapper function fails e.g. when the original accepts brace init lists. I can't just capture them in a std::vector and then relay this. At least that's how I interpreted the error when I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to use a lambda and wrap the call:

```cpp
m.def(
    "func_i_like_to_use",
    [](float a, std::string const& s) {
        return func_i_like_to_use(a, s);
    },
    "Want to call from Python");
```